# Existence of a surface, given a parametrization

Tags: differential-geometry, surfaces

I'm asked if given a map $F:\mathbb{R}^{2}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{3}$, $F(u,v)=(11 \cos(u),11 \sin(u),v)$ is a parametrization of a surface. What I have thought is, well:

1) It's differentiable (each component is differentiable).

2) It's differential is: \begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
-11 \sin(u) & 0\\
11 \cos(u)& 0\\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}.

It's determinant minors are: (a) $11 \cos(u)$, (b) $-11 \sin(u)$, (c) $0$. Respectively are zero if $u=\frac{\pi}{2}+k\pi, v=l\pi, k,l\in\mathbb{Z}$. Fixed (u_{0},v_{0}), DF(u_{0},v_{0}) has rank two always (because there exist some minor determinant that is not zero, is clear that it is no posible that a) and b) be zero at the same time). So, DF is inyective.

3) $F$ is continuous (is clear). To prove that it is an homeomophism I have built it's inverse: $z=v$, $\frac{y}{x}= \tan(u)$, $u= \arctan(\frac{y}{x})$ (whenever $x\neq 0$). So $F^{-1}(x,y,z)=(\arctan(\frac{y}{x}),z)$ is continuous.

- Is $F$ a parametrization if $|u|<1$? If $|v<|1$? What I thought is that in both cases yes, because they don't include points where the condition (2) is false.
- Is $F$ a parametrization if we restrict to $100u < v < 100u +1$? In this case, it is not (because it includes points where the condition (2) is not true).

  I have to determine if it is a local isometry. What I have done is calculate $T_{p}S=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^{3}:<(x,y,z),(\cos(u), \sin(u),0)>=0\}$.
  But to prove $<DF(u),DF(v)>=<u,v>$ for all $u,v\in T_{p}S$.

  Any hint to continue is appreciated!

Comment: Have you thought of how this surface looks? It'll give a lot of intuition. Hint: for $v$, what does varying $u$ do?

Comment: Yes, it's an (infinitely tall) cylinder! You sort of roll the plane into a cylinder along the $u$ direction. Note that $F$ _can't_ be a homeomorphism (onto it's image). It's not even bijective! $(u, v)$ and $(u + 2k\pi, v)$ get mapped to the same point. $F^{-1}$ _does_ provide a local homeomorphism to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is all that's needed to show something is a surface.

Comment: @OsamaGhani Yeah, I thought about it... It looks like a piece of a cilinder, a strip in a cilinder...

Comment: To show local isometry, note that by bilinearity you only have to check for the pairs $\langle e_1,e_1 \rangle, \langle e_1, e_2 \rangle, \langle e_2, e_1 \rangle, \langle e_2, e_2 \rangle$. Can you do this? You'll see that the condition is true for all pairs except for $\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle$, so this is not a local isometry (the $11$ causes the issue here).

Comment: @OsamaGhani I'm going to write down all what you have said  ... Thanks for your help!

Comment: @OsamaGhani Sorry if my question is so basic (I'm not good in differential geometry) but $DF(u,v)(e_{1})=(-11sin(u),11cos(u),0)$ and $DF(u,v)(e_{2})=(0,0,1)$ no? So in this case, we have what you have said.... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write this as a quick answer to point out a few things. As I stated in my comments, you have enough to show that you have a surface. Now we need to check for local isometry. I think you may have used the same notation for a few concepts (such as $u,v$ as coordinates on $\mathbb{R}^2$ but also as tangent vectors to $F(\mathbb{R}^2) = S$) so I'm going to straighten it here.

Let $p = (u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2$. Then $T_p\mathbb{R}^2 \cong \mathbb{R}^2$. Let us denote two tangent vectors here by $x, y \in T_p\mathbb{R}^2$. Note that $DF_p$ is a linear map from $T_p(\mathbb{R}^2) \to T_{F(p)}S$ (represented by the matrix you have, evaluated at $p$). Now, the condition for a local isometry is that
$$\langle x, y \rangle = \langle DF_p(x), DF_p(y) \rangle$$
for all $x, y \in T_p\mathbb{R}^2$ (and not $T_{F(p)} S$ as you wrote).

Instead of checking on every $x_1,x_2$, it suffices to check on every basis combination, because the inner product can be extended by bilinearity. If you're not sure what this means or why it is, let me know. So let us check for the four basis combinations $\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle, \langle e_1, e_2 \rangle, \langle e_2, e_1 \rangle, \langle e_2, e_2 \rangle$. The calculations are below

$$\langle e_1, e_1 \rangle = 1, \langle DF_p(e_1), DF_p(e_1) \rangle = \langle (-11 \sin u, 11 \cos u, 0), (-11 \sin u, 11 \cos u, 0)\rangle = 121 \neq 1$$

$$\langle e_1, e_2 \rangle = 0, \langle DF_p(e_1), DF_p(e_2) \rangle = \langle (-11 \sin u, 11 \cos u, 0), (0, 0, 1)\rangle = 0 $$

$$\langle e_2, e_1 \rangle = 0, \langle DF_p(e_2), DF_p(e_1) \rangle = \langle (0, 0, 1),(-11 \sin u, 11 \cos u, 0)\rangle = 0 $$

$$\langle e_2, e_2 \rangle = 1, \langle DF_p(e_2), DF_p(e_2) \rangle = \langle (0,0,1), (0,0,1)\rangle = 1$$

So here you see it fails for the $e_1, e_1$ pair, so this is not an isometry.

One last thing I would point out to quickly show it's a surface. Note that $S$ is also described by the equation $x^2 + y^2 = 11$. Then note that its a regular value of the function $G: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that $G(x,y,z) = x^2 + y^2 - 11$, and $S = G^{-1}(0)$. Since it's a regular value, it's a surface.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! @OsamaGhani